# Private and secure document storage for mobile use and sharing between 2 people

Tags: pdf, web, privacy

I want to arrange for communication between myself and a friend. Privacy and security are important (there is nothing illegal or even profane). Her mobile and pc computing are monitored by her family. Mine is monitored much less. Any ideas please?

Message frequency would be several per week. We don't need notification of sending or arrival. Location for storage of documents would also be needed.

Some perhaps most of the content will be pdf's of documents. Our families are not capable programmers but we would need security from those who are.

I imagine that this is a common problem but internet searches don't seem promising.

We already use Dropbox for a society that we belong to wher its messages are made available.

We would prefer not to have another app. So a web interface would be good with password protection.

Any ideas please?